# Disable Enter in editText android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an EditText but I want only one line. I put lime this

```xml
<item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
<item name="android:minLines">1</item>
<item name="android:lines">1</item>
```

but doesn't work.

[image]

See my code:

```xml
<LinearLayout style="@style/linearInputEntryText">
    <LinearLayout  style="@style/subLinearLayout">
        <TextView style="@style/label" android:text="Last Name" android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
        <EditText style="@style/editTextEntryName" android:id="@+id/lastName"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/linearInputEntryBlack" > </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

and styles:

```xml
<style name="editTextEntryName" parent="editTextEntry">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:minLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is only possible with inputType multiline I think.

Comment: set `android:singleLine=true` to your `EditText`

Comment: add android:inputType="text" and android:singleLine="true".

Comment: android:singleLine is deprecated it's not a good practice using it

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova Can you give any official reference where you found this information?

Comment: @AritraRoy you are right.I don't see any where, singleLine is deprecated

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Because of different Android versions, the best practice is to include these parameters at the same time:

```
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:lines="1"
         android:singleLine="true"
```

If you don't, it will not work correctly on some devices.

Comment: These answers appear deprecated. What's imprecated is apparently a simple: `android:inputType="text"`, or one of its derivatives: `android:inputType="textCapWords"`. They clear the bit `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE`, which is on by default.

Comment: This doesn't disable enter button

Answer (score 91):

android:maxLines="1" 
allows the text to be multiline but limits the height of edittext to display a single line.

If you want to disable the enter (new line) key, set the input type to text

```
    android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: That is the correct answer! And also if you want to have multiline support use `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

Comment: Perfect!  `android:singleLine` had been deprecated.

Answer (score 25):

Please use

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

instead of

```
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:minLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
```

That single attribute is enough to make your EditText accept only one line of text and disable the enter button.

**UPDATE**

Don't worry about this comment,

> android:singleLine is deprecated it's not a good practice using it

This attributed is officially supported and is not deprecated in any possible way. And it is also guaranteed that this will work in all devices and on all Android versions.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please upvote and accept it.

Comment: Is there any problem with my answer that it is not accepted?

Comment: It is correct, but it is not true that the singleLine param should be used instead of the others you listed. They all should be used together or the TextView will behave incorrectly on selected devices. I have seen it firsthand, it is not a 'maybe' warning.

Comment: @AritraRoy now singleLine is working with me and max lines not, what is that I need to understand? a deprecated wtt is working and a functional one not. Do you have an idea about that ?

Comment: you can delete this answer

Answer (score 9):

You may use

```
<EditText 
   ......
   android:imeOptions="actionNext" OR "actionDone" />
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more?  What are you trying to accomplish, and why does this solution work?

Answer (score 5):

Use xml attribute

```
<EditText
    ......
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me,

by setting onKeyListener for the editText in my onCreateView -

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
        }
});
```

Edit: this may not work if you are using Android default keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:singleLine=true` instead `android:maxLines=1`

Please read about singleLine

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: android:singleLine is deprecated now

Answer (score 2):

Or if you wanna use java you could do this:

```
    edittext1.setSingleLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

use   `android:singleLine="true"` property

```
     <EditText 
       ......
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:id="@+id/lastName"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the input type to textEmailSubject.
I head the same issue and it solve it!