# How to adjust words in a line in multiline text in android studio

Tags: android

How to adjust words in a line in multiline text and how to disable editing in multiline text.

[image]

Comment: define adjustment ? do you mean alignment ? if yes you can refer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381715/android-edit-text-alignment

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
     <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
```

see the accepted answer here
[Disable Enter in editText android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965330/disable-enter-in-edittext-android)

Comment: I want to justify the line or paragraph.